# What is the difference between ‘у тебя’ and ‘твой’?

Tags: местоимения

- У тебя торт / Твой торт
- У меня пирог / Мой пирог

What is the difference?

Comment: "А: Где мой пирог?  Б: У меня твой пирог." A: Where is my pie? B: I have your pie.

Comment: See also [Possessive constructions: “мой” vs. “у меня”](http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/873/551).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У тебя торт = you have a/the cake

Твой торт = your cake

Comment: Sir, then У тебя есть also same.. no?

Comment: @Lee yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2):

Lee,
In phrase using У тебя - is important that action happen with you, so if it's question, I am interested in your situation.
In phrase using Твой is important the fact of possession.

У тебя пирог сгорел - You have burned the cake (I smell smoke in your flat)

Я съел твой пирог, извини - I ate your cake, sorry (It was **your** cake, not mine, but I ate it)

У тебя есть друг? - Do you have a friend? (You, personally, do you have relations of friendships with someone?)

Твой друг придет к нам на вечеринку? - Is your friend going to join our party? (It's **your** friend, so I ask you about him)

Shortly, you don't use У тебя пирог in sense Твой пирог. It's not the same.

Hope, it helps